# VueJs $emit in component not triggered parent when fired in async method

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I have an async method in my component, I want to await for the axios request and then emit an event to the parent.

When in the async/await pattern, the event is emitted but not catch by parent

```
async save() {
  if (this.canSave) {
    await this.savePlot()      
    this.$emit('plot-saved');
  }
}
```

if I set it as a normal function no problem, the parent catch the event :

```
save() {
  if (this.canSave) {
    this.savePlot()      
    this.$emit('plot-saved');
  }
}
```

my component in the parent vue file :

```
<PlotForm @plot-saved="close(true)" />
```

Comment: Looks like savePlot() is never finishing. Have you checked it?

Comment: No, the API is called and I have the status 200 returned. In the Vue devtool of my chrome console I can see that the `plot-saved` event is emitted but never catched by the parent

Comment: Can you show `savePlot`?

Comment: It's an action in my VueX store, but no problem on this side, I repeat, the API call is done and back, if I debug I wait on the `this.savePlot()` and on the `$emit` I see it in the chrome console but not catched by parent

Comment: Right, well there's nothing wrong with the code shown so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure that this.savePlot() is returning a Promise?  Also, try wrapping 'await this.savePlot()' in a try...catch block.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread, when I ended up with the same problem as you had, unfortunately there was no answers here

Never figured out why it was not working. In my code I added console.log after calling with await, but before $emit. The console.log was correctly called, so the problem lies with the $emit functionality

I did manage to find a solution that is useful. Add this nice tool to your project
https://github.com/developit/mitt

In my project I added a variable called emitter in an external normal .js file and added this to the vue code:

```
mounted()
{
        window.emitter = window.mitt();

        window.emitter.on('group-text-closed', this.GroupTextClosed)
},
```

And then in the function that needs to emit, add this instead

```
CloseGroupText()
{
        await SomeApiCallFunctionWorthWaitingFor();

        window.emitter.emit('group-text-closed');
},
```

This also has the added benefit that you can call it in some child deep down and still easily catch it in the root parent

I hope this can help out anybody else who is in the same situation